# Rewrite after 1.0.0-beta

Tags: git, version-control, open-source, versioning, semantic-versioning

Some time ago I've released an open source project with version 1.0.0-beta (it was it's first pre-release).

Currently I'm working on a rewrite (so a lot of code changes and documentation won't be up-to-date anymore).

What version should I give it now? Be aware it's not backwards compatible, and kind of all code changed...

I was thinking about 1.1.0-beta (so skipping 1.0.0-stable).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/)?

Comment: Thats exactly what I try to follow @Kara, I only forgot the name. However, I can't find out how to do this following Semver...

Comment: Naming it 2.0.0 would make the most sense from a semantic versioning standpoint.